# Geotools Runtime error in web application environment?

Tags: geotools

Eclipse+Maven+Tomcat.
I have some Geotools code that runs fine when run as "Java Application".
The same code fails when running within a servlet.
So it must be an issue with the Jar Loader of geotools.

using org.geotools.metadata.iso.citation.Citations throws

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.geotools.metadata.iso.citation.ContactImpl.getOnlineResource()Lorg/opengis/metadata/citation/OnlineResource;
```

The error is thrown in the static part of Citations

```
  final CitationImpl c = new CitationImpl(ResponsiblePartyImpl.OGC);
```

Has anyone any idea?

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.geotools.metadata.iso.citation.ContactImpl.getOnlineResource()Lorg/opengis/metadata/citation/OnlineResource;
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.geotools.metadata.PropertyAccessor.get(PropertyAccessor.java:450)
    at org.geotools.metadata.PropertyAccessor.hashCode(PropertyAccessor.java:773)
    at org.geotools.metadata.MetadataStandard.hashCode(MetadataStandard.java:303)
    at org.geotools.metadata.AbstractMetadata.hashCode(AbstractMetadata.java:198)
    at org.geotools.metadata.PropertyAccessor.hashCode(PropertyAccessor.java:775)
    at org.geotools.metadata.MetadataStandard.hashCode(MetadataStandard.java:303)
    at org.geotools.metadata.AbstractMetadata.hashCode(AbstractMetadata.java:198)
    at java.util.HashMap.hash(HashMap.java:339)
    at java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:612)
    at java.util.HashSet.add(HashSet.java:220)
    at org.geotools.util.CheckedHashSet.add(CheckedHashSet.java:190)
    at org.geotools.metadata.iso.citation.CitationImpl.<init>(CitationImpl.java:156)
    at org.geotools.metadata.iso.citation.Citations.<clinit>(Citations.java:76)
```

Comment: How are you building your war file?

Answer (score 1):

Using version 22-SNAPSHOT solved the problem !